Continuous differentiability of an exponential function at $x=y=0$
I have a function, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \exp(-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) ~\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I have been trying to check whether this function is continuously differentiable (or has bounded derivatives for all real values of $x, y$). The gradients of the function can be found to be
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\end{bmatrix} = \frac{(1-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\exp(-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \begin{bmatrix}{x \\ y}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Now, this function is differentiable at all finite values of $x,y$, except when $x = y= 0$. When we fix $y=0$, we have the following relationship,
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\partial f(x,0)}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f(x,0)}{\partial y}}\end{bmatrix}  = \frac{(1-\sqrt{x^2})\exp(-\sqrt{x^2})}{\sqrt{x^2}} \begin{bmatrix}{x \\ 0}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {\text{sign}(x)(1-|x|)\exp(-|x|) \\ 0} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
It is noticeable that $\frac{\partial f(x,0)}{\partial x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ (provided $\text{sign} (0) = \pm1$). Similar results apply when we have $x=0$ and $y \rightarrow 0$. However, this relationship does not hold, when $x \rightarrow 0,~ y \rightarrow 0$. Further, using L'Hopital's rule at $x=y=0$ induces a recursion, since we have $\frac{\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})}{\partial x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x}$, and it doesn't help either.
Is there any standard way to verify whether this function is continuously differentiable at zero?

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist, also for $y$.

Let $F(x) = f(x,0)= |x|e^{-|x|}$, so $F'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)$. Note that as $$h \to 0+, \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h} \to \frac{1 - 0}{+0} = +\infty$$ while as $$h \to 0-, \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h} \to \frac{1 - 0}{-0} = -\infty$$ so $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h}$ cannot converge. I.e., $F'(0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist.

In answer to your final question: the standard way of determining if a function is differentiable at a given point is to go back to the definition of the derivative, and if needed, of the limit. Doing it that way is generally more work, so first we try other tools that hide that extra work if possible. But when those fail, it is time to go to the definitions.
